# Replace text in a string using PHP

Tags: php, replace, find

I have this string:

```
$my_string = "http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg 4444/8888/7777  http://apinmo.com/4/5/8-1.jpg";
```

And I need to remove the last two slashs of the urls to get this, all the rest remain the same:

```
$my_NEW_string = "http://apinmo.com/123.jpg 4444/8888/7777   http://apinmo.com/458-1.jpg";
```

I tried this:

```
$my_NEW_string = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\/(?=\d)/', '', $my_string);
```

but I get this:

```
$my_NEW_string = "http://apinmo.com/123.jpg 444488887777   http://apinmo.com/458-1.jpg";
```

The slashes in `4444/8888/7777` where removed and this not what I need. They must to remain there.

**UPDATE**: due to the context where this code is used I need this approach: **make replacements between 'http' and 'jpg'**

Comment: why dont you try to get only images url from string ?

Comment: Are the spaces in the string important?

Comment: @JayBlanchard there are spaces in the string. Yes, they shoulb remain as it.

Comment: You can replace since a position in your string. ie from the second space or from the second http position to the end.

Comment: This could help: I only need to make replacements between 'http' and 'jpg'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yet another way to do this and preserve your spaces:

```
$my_string = "http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg 4444/8888/7777  http://apinmo.com/4/5/8-1.jpg";
$string_array = explode(' ', $my_string);
print_r($string_array); // for testing

$new_array = '';
foreach($string_array AS $original) {
    $pos = strpos($original, 'http');
    if(0 === $pos){
        $new = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\/(?=\d)/', '', $original);
        $new_array[] = $new;
    } else {
        $new_array[] = $original;
    }
}
$new_string = implode(' ', $new_array);
echo $new_string;
```

Returns (note the preserved spaces):

```
http://apinmo.com/123.jpg 4444/8888/7777  http://apinmo.com/458-1.jpg
```

---

**EDIT -** Pure regex method:

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/(?<=\/\d)(\/)/', '', $my_string);
echo $new_string;
```

Returns: `http://apinmo.com/123.jpg 4444/8888/7777  http://apinmo.com/458-1.jpg`

*CAVEATS*:
    a. ) works even if there are *no* spaces in the string
    2. ) does not work if any number between `/` is more than one digit in length.
  iii. ) if the second group of digits is like `4444/5/8888` the second slash would get removed here too.

Here is how the regex breaks down:

Using a positive lookbehind to match a `/` followed by a digit `(?<=\/\d)` I can assert what I am looking for - I only want to remove the forward slashes *after* a forward slash followed by a digit. Therefore I can capture the other forward slashes with `(\/)` immediately after the lookbehind.  There is no need to include `http://` to start or  `.jpg` to close out.

Comment: Thanks but it is based in "space". Due to the context where this code is used I need this approach: make replacements between 'http' and 'jpg'

Comment: That is not what you originally asked for @canelones

Comment: If there are spaces then they should remain, that is what I meant, but spaces might not be present, then I can not use them to do this.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will see if I can hack together a solution.

Comment: Is it always single digits between the `/` @canelones?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example you might use :

```
<?php

$my_string = "http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg 4444/8888/7777 http://apinmo.com/4/5/8-1.jpg";
$my_array= split(" ",$my_string); // split it to 3 strings 
$part1=preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\/(?=\d)/', '', $my_array['0']);
$part2=$my_array['1'];
$part3=preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\/(?=\d)/', '', $my_array['2']);

$my_new_string=$part1." ".$part2." ".$part3;
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the spaces.

Comment: What if I have more parts? It will fail if the space is missing.

Comment: I'm not sure i completely understand what you mean by preserve but when you get the three parts you can add as much spaces as you want

Comment: this is an example , if you have basic php knowledge you can alter it really easy

Comment: I need other approach, like making the replacements between 'http' and 'jpg'

Answer (score 0):

If the strings always has images you will get all images in `$matches` array.

As per your comment you need

> This could help: I only need to make replacements between 'http' and 'jpg'.

You can make replace by playing with array as per the requirement.

```
$input = 'http://apinmo.com/123.jpg 4444/8888/7777   http://apinmo.com/458-1.jpg';
preg_match_all('(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))', $input, $matches);

echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://apinmo.com/123.jpg
            [1] => http://apinmo.com/458-1.jpg
        )

)
```